# .htaccess url-rewriting not working properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

I am redirecting from our old webpages, which looked like this:

```
www.domain.com/?content=foo
```

to

```
www.domain.com/bar
```

using The following code in the .htacces file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} content=foo$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bar [L]
```

The redirect works, i am moved to the correct page, but the old url in the browser remains unchanged.

```
www.domain.com/?content=foo
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting instead of redirecting use below rule,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} content=foo$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bar [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, unfortunately this is dropping a server error 500.

Comment: This drops a 403. The query string remains in the url...if it would not, it would be fine, i guess..